Bass in Sound fails sometimes
I sometimes have the problem that the bass in my sound is missing/failed. When I restart the system, the bass is back.
Software Info:

Realtek Audio
FxSound

The problem is NOT solved by disabling FxSound (at least if I do it with the button in FxSound).
I would like to have a permanent solution or a way to solve it without rebooting everytime.

it happend again just now.
